# Выбор пустого элемента массива

Tags: c#

Есть двумерный массив, он заполняется в цикле случайным образом, в итоге, когда остаётся только один не заполненный элемент, цикл завершается, а координаты элемента выводятся.

Comment: Сформулируй вопрос яснее. Не очень понятно, что требуется сделать.

Comment: Короче есть двумерный массив, предположим 10 на 10, 99 элементов имеют значение, а один - NULL, или пустая строка, нужно вывести номер этого элемента.

Comment: смотря как заполняешь и ищешь....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

работает с произвольными типами, для чисел пустым элементом является 0, для строк - пустая строка, для классов - null

```
public static int[] IndexOfEmptyElement<T>(this T[,] array)
{
    for(int i=array.GetLength(0)-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(int j=array.GetLength(1)-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(array[i,j], default(T)))
                return new int[]{i, j};
        }
    }

    return new int[]{};
}

public static int CountOfEmptyElements<T>(this T[,] array)
{
    var count = 0;    
    for(int i=array.GetLength(0)-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(int j=array.GetLength(1)-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(array[i,j], default(T)))
                count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

использование:

```
var a = new int[3,3]{{1,2,3},{0,4,5},{6,7,8}};
if(a.CountOfEmptyElements() == 1)
   a.IndexOfEmptyElement().Dump(); // [1,0]
```

**UPD:** Обновил ответ

Comment: А так, чтоб ещё определял один пустой, или нет??

Comment: "System.Array" не содержит определения для "CountOfEmptyElements" и не был найден метод расширения "CountOfEmptyElements", принимающий тип "System.Array" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

И тоже самое для IndexOfEmptyElement

Comment: почитайте про [Extention Methods](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=extension+methods), узнаете, что методы расширения должны содержаться в статическом классе